# Are numbers such as 5 technically references or values?

Tags: c++, variables, reference

This is sort of a philosophical question, but maybe there's an answer in the C++ standard.

Take, for example,

```
int x = 5;
```

Is this assigning `x` to the value `5`, or is assigning `x` to be a reference to `5`, which itself has some inherent value? Is `5` a real thing or is it an idea?

Comment: `std::is_reference<int>::value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an `rvalue`. If you are into platonic theory then it's an idea real as me and you. Even though I'm not sure about me and you.

Comment: What if I want to make `5` act like `0`, that is, make `5` be the number such that i+5=5 for any `int i`, via `#define 5 0` ? Have I violated the definition of an `rvalue`?

Comment: @SteveBahlmer, that's not a legal `#define`.

Comment: @SteveBahlmer That makes no sense.

Comment: Is there a correct way that I can make 5 act like 0?

Comment: 5 cannot act like 0. That is one of the basic laws of mathematics.

Comment: Can you restate your original question in terms of your programming problem? What is the problem you're having where you think making 5 act like 0 will solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In the statement:

```
int x = 5;
```

The 5 is a constant number.
The variable `x` is assigned the value of `5`.
No references involved.

In most compilers and platforms, there is no reference made for the number.  Also, the number is usually placed directly into the executable code and not in a data segment.  This is because it's storage requirements are small and the number doesn't change.